# Custom fork of a package migrations for heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

The package fork to which I am referring has no `manage.py`, so it's not like I can just do a `manage.py makemigrations` when I add fields to a model. Can anyone help?

Here is the package: https://github.com/shanbay/django-vote

And here is my fork: https://github.com/mike-johnson-jr/django-vote

I added `ip` field to a model in the package (and some other minor edits). I need to make these migrations and migrate so my web app that uses this forked package can function properly. Will I need to add these migrations manually?

More information:

So, my package forked package works propertly locally because I was able to run `makemigrations` in my project locally. I can't do that in heroku (well I can, but they are not actually added and `migrate` cannot be used with them).

I am trying to get my forked package running in production -- it is being hosted at heroku and the migrations do not make it over to the production server. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

Is this a separate package that would be added in *conjunction* with a django app? If so, you should add it to your `requirements.txt`, which you can [add as a url link](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/1.1/requirements.html#requirements-file-format), and then add it to your `INSTALLED_APPS`, and then you should be able to run `python manage.py makemigrations`, git push the changes to Heroku, and then run `heroku run python migrate` (assuming you have the [Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli) installed).

If you dont have Heroku CLI, you can always open the console in Heroku for that app, and run the second command. Heroku dyno instances are ephemeral, but database changes stick.

Comment: yes the package is in my requirements.txt, and yes the package is in my installed apps. I've run makemigrations locally, and code that uses the package runs fine locally (and yes I've pushed changes and migrated at the heroku server), as I said in my OP. Running makemigrations on the heroku server does nothing. I need to get this working in production.

Comment: what happens when you run `heroku run python manage.py showmigrations`?

Comment: @maj, there's no reason to run `makemigrations` on Heroku in the first place. By the time you're deploying your code there should be no model changes and therefore nothing for `makemigrations` to do. Only run `makemigrations` locally, and make sure to commit your migration files. Run `migrate` locally and also in production, as Hybrid says in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

uninstalled forked package, cloned forked package in local repo, installed with pip -e /path/to/package (editable pip install), then ran makemigrations so migrations could be saved to the actual cloned fork, pushed changes to github, purged heroku cache, redownloaded forked package and ran migrate, worked